# How to keep and loop the style of HTML element from an Array in REACT?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a form builder, so one of my requirements is users should be able to add style.
So far these are the options I tried but it's not working

**Option 1**

**State 1**

```
const [myStyle, setStyle] = useState("border: '2px solid red', color: 'yellow'")
```

**Element 1**

```
<div style={{myStyle}}>Hello First Trial</div>
```

---

**Option 2**

**state 2**

```
const [myStyle, setStyle] = useState([
     {name: 'border', value:'2px solid red'},
     {name: 'color', value:'yellow'} 
])
```

**Element 2**

```
<div style={{myStyle.map(style=> {
                     return {style.name:style.value}}}>
                    Hello Second Trial
</div>
```

Comment: You need this: https://jsfiddle.net/76zh9os8/ (a style object and `style={myStyle}`)

Comment: Why don't you go with "option 1" but make "myStyle" an object, rather than a string? `const [myStyle, setStyle] = useState({ border: '...', color: '...' })` and then `<div style={ myStyle }>`

Comment: try this --> `myStyle.map(sty => (<div style={sty}>Hello</div>))`

Comment: Guy thank you so much, all your answers helped me :D!

Comment: @SarunUK that will render multiple divs, each with just one rule applied to them. Not what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

use this one it works fine

```
const [myStyle, setStyle] = useState({border: '2px solid red', color: 'yellow'})
```

and

```
<div style={myStyle}>Hello First  Trial</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:-**

```
const [myStyle, setStyle] = useState({border: '2px solid red', color: 'yellow'})

<div style={myStyle}>Hello First  Trial</div></div>
```

**Option 2:-**

```
const [myStyle, setStyle] = useState([
     {name: 'border', value:'2px solid red'},
     {name: 'color', value:'yellow'} 
])
```

Use **reduce** method to prepare a single object out of the array.

```
    <div
    style={myStyle?.reduce((agg, val) => {
      agg[val.name] = val.value;
      return agg;
    }, {})}
  >
    Hello Second Trial
  </div>
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wildflower-sutkr?file=/src/App.js:294-495